# Pre caching webpage when app loading in ios

Tags: iphone, objective-c, web-applications, ios6, uiwebview

I've problem in ios that loading webpage in UIWebView is getting too slow at first time.It is possible to pre cache the specific webpage when loading the app, Then show that pre cached webpage on where I want in the app.How to fix it ? or Please give any guidelines...

Comment: in your web view what type of data you want to show?

Comment: i need to show the whole web page that may contains images,contents and all. its is a shopping website.

Comment: so you are getting data from webservice right?

Comment: Say for an example,I want to store all the data of a yahoo page(image,text,everything) and next time I want to this data to show the yahoo page again in the webview even without net also.

Comment: in that case you have to store entire data in local at that time only you'l get data without internet for that use data base and download the images .